# i want a Navbar fixed to top but not to the top of the body but to top from a container in the middle of my page but it go to the top page

Tags: css

i want a Navbar fixed to top but not to the top of the body but to top from a container in the middle of my page but it go to the top page , i want a Navbar fixed to top but not to the top of the body but to top from a container in the middle of my page but it go to the top page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>


 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    

<div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" `enter code here`class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want to make like this but in the middle of the page at a container not on the body

Comment: can you make it simple to understand ??

Comment: sorry , i mean i want it to be fixed at the top of a div not fixed at the top of the whole page

Comment: just remove the fixed class then

Comment: but i want it to be fixed like this one http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp , but the difference that i want it to be fixed at a container not to all the body

Comment: so you just need that when section 1 appears then it hover the section 1 nav or  you just need a header to be fixed at section 1 then its static ??

Comment: yes the first one (when section 1 appears then it hover the section 1 nav)

Comment: it working fine to me that section 1 apears on div 1 second to 2 div ??